# Document search using elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search and need a help to understand how to search a text from the list of documents using elastic search.For example user uploads a list of documents through my application and based on some keywords like name,age i have to get the documents.

I have tried a lot to get a sample java program to understand how elastic search works in the above scenario.could some one help me to get sample program.

I have done file searching using apache lucene,but it is not working.Could some one help me to find what is wrong in the code

public class App {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String path = "D:\\input\\output\\test.txt";      
    List<File> files = getFiles(path);

    createIndex(files);
    List<String> searchkeywords = new ArrayList<String>();
    searchkeywords.add("sample");
    int count = searchIndex(searchkeywords);
    System.out.println("count :: "+count);

}   

public static void createIndex(List<File> files) throws IOException {
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("index"));
    IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, iwc);
    for (File file : files) {
        Document document = new Document();
        Field pathField = new StringField("contents", file.toString(), Field.Store.YES);
        document.add(pathField);
        if (indexWriter.getConfig().getOpenMode() == IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE) {
            System.out.println("adding " + file);
            indexWriter.addDocument(document);
        } else {
            System.out.println("updating " + file);
            indexWriter.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.toString()), document);
            indexWriter.addDocument(document);
        }
        indexWriter.close();
    }
}


public static int searchIndex(List<String> searchStrings) throws IOException, ParseException {
    int maxCount = 0;
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("index")));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("contents", analyzer);
    for (String searchString : searchStrings) {
        Query query = parser.parse(searchString);
        TopDocs result = searcher.search(query, 10);
        maxCount += result.totalHits;
    }
    return maxCount;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you paste your code here?

Comment: Dont have code by using elastic search.I have done it using apache lucene,but need sample piece of code to understand how to search a text from list of documents using elastic search.

Comment: I have done file searching using apache lucene,but it is not working.Could some one help me to find what is wrong in the code